# Identify caller ID using Call Directory Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, caller-id

I have implemented Call Directory Extension in my app to identify called id. But not able to view my apps name or caller detail, when a call is received. Not able to debug Call Directory Extension, sue to security reasons by Apple. Have included my code below.

```
override func beginRequest (with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
// --- 1
guard let phoneNumbersToBlock = retrievePhoneNumbersToBlock () else {
NSLog ( "Unable to retrieve phone numbers to block" )
let error = NSError (domain: "CallDirectoryHandler" , code: 1 , userInfo: nil )
context.cancelRequest (withError: error)
return
}

// --- 2
for phoneNumber in phoneNumbersToBlock {
    let phoneNumberr : CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber = CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)!
context.addBlockingEntry (withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumberr)
}

// --- 3
guard let (phoneNumbersToIdentify, phoneNumberIdentificationLabels) = retrievePhoneNumbersToIdentifyAndLabels () else {
NSLog ( "Unable to retrieve phone numbers to identify and their labels" )
let error = NSError (domain: "CallDirectoryHandler" , code: 2 , userInfo: nil )
context.cancelRequest (withError: error)
return
}

// --- 4
for (phoneNumber, label) in zip (phoneNumbersToIdentify, phoneNumberIdentificationLabels) {
    let phoneNumberrr : CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber = CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)!
context.addIdentificationEntry (withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumberrr, label: label)
}

// --- 5
context.completeRequest ()
}

private func retrievePhoneNumbersToBlock () -> [ String ]? {
 // retrieve list of phone numbers to block
 return [ "+ 919488775260" ]
 }

 private func retrievePhoneNumbersToIdentifyAndLabels () -> (phoneNumbers: [ String ], labels: [ String ])? {
 // retrieve list of phone numbers to identify, and their labels
 return ([ "+ 919385338505" ], [ "test" ])
 }
```

Should any configuration be enabled, which i might have missed out. Please help me.

Comment: Are you testing with Indian numbers or North American numbers?  Have you enabled your directory extension in the "phone" settings?  You can debug call,directory extensions using Xcode. Note that the extension code runs when you enable the extension (or reload it from your main app), not when an incoming call arrives

Comment: Yes you are rite

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Basically debugging Call directory extension is not possible, due to security reasons by Apple. But you can test it through reload function in app. Please find the code below.

```
CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "com.harman.CallerIDTestApp.CallerExtension", completionHandler: { (result: Error?)->Void in
        guard let errorChk = result else { return }
        print(errorChk)
        let errorCode = (errorChk as NSError).code
        switch errorCode {
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.unknown.rawValue:
            print("Extension could not be load for an unknown reason.")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.noExtensionFound.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  Extension not found")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.loadingInterrupted.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  Extension was interrupted while loading")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.entriesOutOfOrder.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  Call entries are out of order")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.duplicateEntries.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  Duplicate entries")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.maximumEntriesExceeded.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  Maximum entries exceeded")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.extensionDisabled.rawValue:
            print("Extension not enabled in Settings")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.unexpectedIncrementalRemoval.rawValue:
            print("Unexpected incremental removal")
        case CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError.Code.currentlyLoading.rawValue:
            print("Could not load extension.  The extension is currently loading")
        default:
            print("Could not load extension.")
        }
    })
```

Use the above code in app delegate to test if your call directory extension is working.

In "CallDirectoryHandler",beginRequest method should as below.

```
override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    context.delegate = self
    if context.isIncremental {
        addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context)

        addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
    } else {
        addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context)

        addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
    }

    context.completeRequest()
}
```

Please check if context is isIncremental, else the code will not work.

Comment: What a great suggestion on debugging the extension.  Thanks so much!